How sending custom messages with bugsnag-laravel to assign custom tags for later filtering?
I have added "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel" v2.28 into my Laravel 11 / Livewire 3.5 app. I am also reading the docs here:
https://app.bugsnag.com/accounts/myaccount/projects/myproject/integrate
I did not find if sending messages at Bugsnag with code like
Route::get('/check-bugsnag', function () {
    Bugsnag::notifyException(new RuntimeException("check-bugsnag Test error #3"));
    return 'check-bugsnag is working well';
});

I can attach some custom tags and then in Bugsnag project console to make filter by these tags ?
Here https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/#declaring-feature-flags-and-experiments I found "Declaring feature flags and experiments" article.
But changing code above as :
Route::get('/check-bugsnag', function () {
    Bugsnag::addFeatureFlag('Checkout button color', 'Blue');
    Bugsnag::notifyException(new RuntimeException("check-bugsnag Test error #3"));
    return 'check-bugsnag is working well';
});

I did not find any feature flag in description of the error. Is addFeatureFlag not what I need in this case? What have I to use here ?
"bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.0",
"laravel/framework": "^11.9",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.5",

Update
I made in my code :
Bugsnag::notifyException(
    new Exception('A notified exception with metadata'),
    function(Report $report) {
        $report->setMetaData([
            'Issue Details' => [
                'path' => 'notify-with-metadata',
                'function' => 'Shows how to send extra data with a manually notified exception!',
                'issue_type' => 'issueTag'
            ],
        ]);
        // Possible values : 'info', 'error'
        $report->setSeverity('warning');
    }
);

What I see in Bugsnag console :

That is good, Next I try to search my custom attribute 'issue_type' => 'issueTag' like :

Which kind of format filter must be to find my data ?

"Exceptions are not reported when running in the Tinker shell." are you using the browser/postman?

have u followed this installation?

Here is their code example, copy paste and tell if works..

Thanks! @francisco,  Please read Additive Code

give the link..

Which LInk? What is unclear for me how correctly make search condition with my custom data 'Issue Details' => 'issue_type' ?
